# what's synchronous about javascript synchronous code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

since synchronous means at the same time and regular javascript operates sequentially, line after line, why isn't js synchronous called asynchronous? Likewise, why isn't asynchronous called synchronous as two things are happening at the same time

Comment: Asynchronous doesn't mean that two things happen at the same time, but that some things will happen *later*.

Comment: [Synchronous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synchronous) doesn't mean that two statements (lines) execute at the same time, but is derived from the fact that the code runs in phase with the computer clock signal, with the normal flow of time.

Comment: `Synchronization is the coordination of events to operate a system in unison. For example, the conductor of an orchestra keeps the orchestra synchronized or in time. Systems that operate with all parts in synchrony are said to be synchronous or in sync—and those that are not are asynchronous.` via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization so synchronous doesn't mean `at the same time` but `in sequence` and scheduled while our async code in js is branching off into their own timelines if you will.

Comment: @DCR No two code block are executed at the same time. Rather, executing one block of code causes another block of code to be executed later, without the two being synchronized (by direct calls/jumps). Did have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Javascript is synchronous because execution is "in sync" with parsing.

A line is parsed, then executed.

Then, the next line is parsed, then executed.

Each line is parsed, then executed, in turn.

Asynchronicity is when Javascript cannot immediately execute a line after parsing it because it **needs to wait**, first, for a server to send a response or for a `Promise` to be resolved.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Lines are not parsed on their own, and not executed right after parsing.

Comment: _“A line is parsed, then executed.”_ — That’s not what’s happening. The entire script (or module) needs to be parsed before execution. Then all statements are resolved within the parse tree and executed, e.g. `a = b + c * d` → `a = (b + c * d)` → `a = (b + (c * d))`. These things happen sequentially, but asynchronous code isn’t special, in general. Mostly it’s just callback functions that get called at some later point. This has nothing to do with the way lines are parsed. `async`–`await` and `yield` may be special as they pause execution within a function, but that’s about it.

Comment: I deleted this answer last night, but I also went to sleep thinking about it and concluded the comments and downvotes above are nitpicking. It's simply never the case that in a six line javascript (which doesn't use _setTimeout_ or _fetch()_ or _Promise_ etc.) that the six lines will be executed in some arbitrary random order. Instead the first line to be executed will be line 1, the fourth line to be executed will be line 4 and the last line to be executed  will be line 6. For the purposes of explaining _why_ Javascript is described as _synchronous_, this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous in js means tasks are performed one after the other, each waits for the previous to complete before starting. This results in a straightforward, line-by-line execution pattern. Asynchronous execution allows tasks to start and then lets the program continue without waiting for them to finish, using callbacks, promises, or async/await for handling completion. Asynchronous operations are of course essential for non-blocking tasks like network requests.

Below are trivial examples on both:

Synchronous example:

```
console.log('First');
console.log('Second');
```

Asynchronous example:

```
console.log('First');
setTimeout(() => console.log('Second'), 1000); // this line executes after 1 second
console.log('Third'); // this line executes directly (before the setTimeout callback)
```

Answer (score -1):

Synchronous JS code waits for the previous line to be executed even if the next line does not require the output result of the previous line.
While Async. JS code does not wait for the previous code to complete execution and runs it in background while continuing executing next lines of code.

We can use `promise`, `async` and `await` to use these functionalities.

while `async` makes a function Async. so it can run in background, `await` makes Async. code Sync. so JS waits for it to complete execution.

for more details : [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Comment: No, `async` does not make something run in the background.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me there is an overlap in the descriptive use of synchronous for a native script or an external script. JavaScript code is asynchronous line by line within the JS code.

The confusion here is describing normal, deferred and asynchronous parsing of an external JS script; from HTML. The HTML follows a normal (synchronous) parsing, and when it encounters a  tag it stops parsing the HTML until the script resource (or module) is parsed before continuing with parsing the HTML.