# Why it's called Synchronous while it means Asynchronous | Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm not an English native speaker.
The word synchronous and asynchronous have always been confusing to me while I learn about them in coding.

Linguistically,
synchronous means: existing or occurring at the same time
and
asynchronous means: not existing or occurring at the same time

In Javascript, for example,

synchronous means:
single-threaded and blocking.
only one operation can be in progress at a time.
code instructions run in sequence.

and

asynchronous means: running in parallel

how did that happen? asynchronous in programming holds the meaning of synchronous linguistically.
am I missing something?

Comment: i just found a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596589/why-are-asynchronous-processes-not-called-synchronous

Comment: Think about it in terms of people queuing.  If there are two or more queues (parallel), then people don't have to wait for people in the other queues (asynchronous).  You always have to wait for people in your *own* queue though or if there *is* only one queue (that's synchronous).

Comment: Super important: asynchronous does _not_ mean parallel. Asynchronous only means "not necessarily running tasks in the same order as written down". A task scheduler can run instructions asynchronously in a single thread just fine.

Comment: The word "synchronous" has [several definitions](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/synchronous). Besides the general definition with which you're familiar ("1. occurring at the same time"), it has a specialized definition in computing: "5. relating to or being a computer operation that must complete before another event can begin".

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258642/whats-synchronous-about-javascript-synchronous-code

Answer (score 2):

Aychronous in JavaScript means "running at a different time", with particular emphasis on not running in the same call out from the event loop's task manager. It does not usually mean "running in parallel" with the main thread<sup>1</sup>.

As an example, if a script fetches data from the network, the fetch operation takes time to perform and the initiating code does not wait for it to complete. Instead it will be notified of the result later, in a call back function, a promise handler or by using `await` in an `async` function.

Note `async` functions store their execution context after returning a promise to the calling code for the result or an `await` operation and return to the event loop (task manager) after adding `then` and `catch` handlers to the awaited promise which will restore the `async` functions execution context and resume execution.

---

<sup>1</sup> Service workers come closest to running in parallel, possibly running in a different CPU core, but have tightly controlled data exchange mechanisms tp avoid simultaneous access to data by the main and worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

**Synchronous** does not mean single-threaded,
**asynchronous** does not mean parallel

**Async** - not schedule (no specifed start time) - *run whenever he can*

**Sync** - schedule (specifed start time - sequence) -
*after function not start if before not run*

That means in any language...

***Async*** can be *one thread, concurrent or parallel*

At the same time, the same program is playing on all TV sets, it has a fixed schedule, therefore it is synchronized. Asynchronously, he wouldn't have and wouldn't play at the same time(or played), that's why.

At the same time, everyone has lessons at school(have schedule).The schedule may be different, it could be in sequence, not all at once. Asynchronous can be all at once, sequence indifferently.

At the same time means a schedule and not that the functions are executed at the same time.

Therefore, the **asynchronous** function when it finds a free thread will execute without waiting for the previous one to finish and will not block the next one as long as there is a free **thread**(then it will be parallel
),
provided the programming language or specific function supports threads, otherwise it will just be async

**async**: (3) (1) (2)

**sync**: (1) (2) (3)

**parallel:**

(1)

(3)

(2)

**concurrent:**:

--(1)

------  (2)

-------------(3)

Sorry for my english i use translator

Comment: "*harmonograme*" doesn't appear to be an English term

Comment: Sorry, schedule, I'am correcting